# linq search functionality skip where clause if null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

How to skip where statement if the typical value is null in LINQ? This is for search functionality in which the user input null value than LINQ will not perform the query on that column.

I remember I saw a direct functionality for that but i forgot on what clause is that. the example given does not require to explicit check for null for each where statement.

Something like this. but i forgot what function should be replaced for the where clause. WhereIf? WhereIff?

```
  db.Table1.Where(x=> x.Column1 == value1)
           .Where(x => x.Column2 == value2)
```

Answer (score 1):

WhereIf should do it.  Have a look here:

This should help you: http://extensionmethod.net/csharp/ienumerable-t/whereif

also look at this answer: [How to use whereif in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771990/how-to-use-whereif-in-linq)

Change your datatable to IQueryable:

db.Table1.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()...

Comment: ya i was thinking of whereif but intellisense does not show me whereif. is it  whereif clause is something that user extend themself or is it linq to sql or linq to object?

Answer (score 0):

If there's a condition you wouldn't want to apply a filter over the query sent to database, then don't call Where on it.

```
var query = db.Table1.AsQueryable();
if (value1 != null)
  query = query.Where(x=> x.Column1 == value1);
if (value2 != null)
  query = query.Where(x=> x.Column2 == value2);

return query.ToList();
```

If `value` is a string, you could test for `string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)`