# Cannot access variable on mapping (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, automapper

I have a method on the back end, that gets values related to a foreign key of the table.

Those foreign keys can be nullable, but one of those keys always will have value.

Here is method

```
   public async Task<ListResultDto<QuoteListDto>> GeQuotesTabData(int? landlordId, int? agentId,
        int? propertyTenantId)
    {

        if (landlordId.HasValue)
        {
            var query = _quoteRepository.GetAll()
                .Where(x => x.LandlordId == landlordId);

        }

        if (agentId.HasValue)
        {
            var query = _quoteRepository.GetAll()
                .Where(x => x.AgentId == agentId);
        }

        if (propertyTenantId.HasValue)
        {
            var query = _quoteRepository.GetAll()
                .Where(x => x.PropertyTenantId == propertyTenantId);
        }

        return new ListResultDto<QuoteListDto>(await query.ProjectTo<QuoteListDto>(ObjectMapper)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToListAsync());
    }
```

At this row, I get an error  `Cannot resolve symbol query`

```
 return new ListResultDto<QuoteListDto>(await query.ProjectTo<QuoteListDto>(ObjectMapper)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToListAsync());
```

How do I need to rewrite my method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is variable scope. When you define a variable it is only visible in the scope you define it in.

You define three different `query` variables in a local scope. None of them are accessible where you try to use it.

You need to define it before using it, something like this:

```
public async Task<ListResultDto<QuoteListDto>> GeQuotesTabData(int? landlordId, int? agentId,
    int? propertyTenantId)
{
    IQueryable<Quote> query = null;

    if (landlordId.HasValue)
    {
        query = _quoteRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.LandlordId == landlordId);
    }

    if (agentId.HasValue)
    {
        query = _quoteRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.AgentId == agentId);
    }

    if (propertyTenantId.HasValue)
    {
        query = _quoteRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.PropertyTenantId == propertyTenantId);
    }

    return new ListResultDto<QuoteListDto>(await query.ProjectTo<QuoteListDto>(ObjectMapper)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToListAsync());
}
```

Of course all of your queries should be of the same type. Otherwise you will have to define and execute them in the local scopes.

You should probably also add some error handling of the case where query is null, when you try to use it.

Comment: Yes, but when I write it like this

`IQueryable<Quote> query;`

I get this one `Local variable query must be initialized`

Comment: Set it to null.

Answer (score 3):

Declare and initialise your variable. Additionally I would re-write you method like so:

```
public async Task<ListResultDto<QuoteListDto>> GeQuotesTabData(int? landlordId, int? agentId,
    int? propertyTenantId)
{
    var query = _quoteRepository.GetAll();

    if (landlordId.HasValue)
    {
        query  = query.Where(x => x.LandlordId == landlordId);
    }

    if (agentId.HasValue)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.AgentId == agentId);
    }

    if (propertyTenantId.HasValue)
    {
        query = query .Where(x => x.PropertyTenantId == propertyTenantId);
    }

    return new ListResultDto<QuoteListDto>(await query.ProjectTo<QuoteListDto>(ObjectMapper)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToListAsync());
}
```

Also taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14772064/5784635) answer, you can create a `WhereIf` extension to clean up the if statements.

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    bool condition,
    Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
{
    if (condition)
        return source.Where(predicate);
    else
        return source;
}
```

Making your code look like this:

```
public async Task<ListResultDto<QuoteListDto>> GeQuotesTabData(int? landlordId, int? agentId,
    int? propertyTenantId)
{
    var list = await  _quoteRepository.GetAll()
        .WhereIf(landlordId.HasValue, x => x.LandlordId == landlordId)
        .WhereIf(agentId.HasValue, x => x.AgentId == agentId)
        .WhereIf(propertyTenantId.HasValue, x => x.PropertyTenantId == propertyTenantId)
        .ProjectTo<QuoteListDto>(ObjectMapper)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
        .ToListAsync();

    return new ListResultDto<QuoteListDto>(list);
}
```

Comment: `WhereIf` must be  without the semicolon at the end