# Entity Framework's translation of LINQ expressions (dynamic conditions error)

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm encountering an issue with Entity Framework's translation of LINQ expressions to SQL queries when using a method that involves dynamic conditions

```
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetKeyValueAsync<TEntity, TKey, TValue>
    (
        this IQueryable<TEntity> queryable,
        KeyValueFilters<TKey?> filters,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>> keySelector,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>> valueSelector
    )
    {
        var term = filters.Term?.ToLower().Trim();
        var id = filters.Id;

        var keyCompliled = keySelector.Compile();
        var valueCompliled = valueSelector.Compile();

        var query = queryable
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Key = keyCompliled.Invoke(x),
                Value = valueCompliled.Invoke(x)
            })

            .WhereIf(id != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(term), x => x.Key!.ToString() == id!.ToString())
            .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(term), x => x.Value!.ToString()!.ToLower().Contains(term!))

            .Take(5)
            .ToList();

        var data = query.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(x.Key, x.Value));

        return data;
    }
```

I'm encountering the following error when executing the above code:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<SubscriptionType>()
    .Where(s => __ef_filter__p_0 || !(EF.Property<bool>(s, "IsDeleted")) && __ef_filter__p_1 || (Guid?)EF.Property<Guid>(s, "TenantId") == __ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_2)
    .Where(s => __keyCompliled_0.Invoke(s).ToString() == __ToString_2)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<SubscriptionType>()
    .Where(s => __ef_filter__p_0 || !(EF.Property<bool>(s, "IsDeleted")) && __ef_filter__p_1 || (Guid?)EF.Property<Guid>(s, "TenantId") == __ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_2)
```

Please note, all is working fine except when conditions (WhereIf) are applied within the query. The error specifically occurs in scenarios where conditional logic is used to filter the data.

Comment: What is this `WhereIf` method? Also, please note that entity framework != linq-to-sql. See tag descriptions. Apart from that: the exception has nothing to with the code you show: it shows a totally different predicate. Where does that come from? (`EF.Property<bool>(s, "IsDeleted")`, etc.). The most troubling thing, however, is that you don't do anything with `IQueryable` after the `Select`. Because of the `Func` objects in the `Select`, EF auto-switches to client-side evaluation and nothing after that can ever be translated into SQL.

Comment: In that sense, it doesn't matter what `WhereIf` is. It's not the cause of the exception anyway. You don't show any code that causes it. All in all, you should change your code entirely to enable predicates that get translated into SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and insights.
The 'WhereIf' method is an extension designed to apply a condition only when a specific 'if' statement evaluates to true. It’s true, the 'WhereIf' isn’t the cause of the exception; it’s more about how the conditions are structured within the LINQ query.

Regarding the 'IsDeleted' global filter, it's intended to ensure that deleted records aren't fetched, thereby acting as a global exclusion criterion.

The issue arises from the specific snippet:

```
.WhereIf(id != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(term), x => x.Key!.ToString() == id!.ToString())
```

Comment: The problem lies in this line:

.WhereIf(id != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(term), x => x.Key!.ToString() == id!.ToString())

'.Where(s => __keyCompliled_0.Invoke(s).ToString() == __ToString_2)' could not be translated,

Comment: As I explained, this `Select` with `Func`s is the main issue, here. What's the reason for this overly flexible method? Are there so many places where it's called that it's justified to have it at all? And if so, why? What makes the code so `KeyValuePair`-greedy?

Comment: Centralizing the code into a single function eliminates repetition across multiple places, streamlining maintenance. I've created a function that generates these key-value pairs using parameters for keys and values, ensuring a consistent format throughout your code. For instance, {key: '1', value: 'ali'}.

Comment: What is your suggestion: to repeat the code or something else?

Answer (score 0):

At first, I thougth that `WhereIf` could not be translated to a database script but it seems like it can.

The reel answer is : That function **can't** be used on `IQueryable` objects. It works on `IEnumerable`.

See this link : [How to use whereif in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771990/how-to-use-whereif-in-linq)

You could either turn your `this IQueryable<TEntity> queryable` by this `this IEnumerable<TEntity> queryable` or you can reformulate (it's going to be slower though) :

```
    var query = queryable
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Key = keyCompliled.Invoke(x),
            Value = valueCompliled.Invoke(x)
        })
         
        .ToList()

        .WhereIf(id != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(term), x => x.Key!.ToString() == id!.ToString())
        .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(term), x => x.Value!.ToString()!.ToLower().Contains(term!))

        .Take(5)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, The issue doesn't lie with them ('WhereIf' and 'Where').

Comment: I don't understand why it works in the select statement but not in the where condition. It only checks the value that comes from the select query.

Comment: You said 'all is working fine except when conditions (WhereIf) are applied within the query' so the problem definitly is related to that, so I don't undestand your first comment. Also, I made an edit to show you how this could be solved.

Comment: Thank you. In the first comment, I meant there is no issue with the WhereIf extension; the issue lies within the predicate function inside it.

Your solution will retrieve all data from the database and then select only 5

Comment: Fetching all the data and then filtering in-memory isn't ideal for performance, especially with large datasets.